# $translate could not load locale value from server

Tags: angularjs, translate

In AngularJS $translate could not load locale value from server, though it is working in local

```
$translate(['ONE_TIME']).then(function (translations) {
    console.log(translations.ONE_TIME);  // This works in local but not from server
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the perceived error? Can you verify translate can load the translations? Maybe your browsers language is different? Maybe you got the URL wrong?

Comment: Translation is working if I use translate in HTML tag, locally as well in server. this problem I am seeing on server, when we try to do using controller. It does not show any error. translations variable store the key (eg - ONE_TIME) as value. In locale we have ONE_TIME = "one time". but the value(one time) does not come when we load the application in server.

Comment: What do you mean by 'server'? The angular controller is running in the browser on the client. How do you use angular-translate in HTML-tags on the server? Do you prerender the site?

Comment: I meant remotely deployed server.